# Sidebar admin LTE laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, dashboard, adminlte

I am using admin LTE in laravel I want to show in dashboard what I click in menu sidebar I want do it with routes.php, but is showing in another page.  How I do that?

Comment: You might want to add some code that you have as a working example as we're are here to help debug. Not write the code fro you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!